# getOpts in perl return null values , as I think

Tags: perl

first of all , I have no experience with perl language 
I am working in a code that has been published from http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/sos/software/index.html
( at the bottom of the page there are two files , the perl file findAccessPatterns.pl and the package is nfsparse.pm

the code has been used in 2003 for analysis an access log file.

I am trying to run the code but this line seems to return empty values.

```
getopts('e:dhm:l:w:', \%opts);
```

could please any one help me to run this code , please please

Comment: Did you specify any command line options when you ran the program?

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. What parameters did you pass to the script? What values do you get (`use Data::Dumper; print(Dumper(\%opts));`? What values do you expect?

Comment: It may be helpful read the `getopts` documentation at http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Std.html

Answer (score 1):

Use this test program

```
use Getopt::Std;

getopts('e:dhm:l:w:', \%opts);

use Data::Dumper;

print Dumper(\%opts);
```

"Data::Dumper" and it's function "Dumper()" display data from things like hashes in a readable form

example of what happens when you run this test program

```
$ perl g.pl -e asdf -dm
$VAR1 = {
          'e' => 'asdf',
          'm' => undef,
          'd' => 1
        };
```